# How does java lib deal with the received data when socket read timeout?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

If a socket reads timeout(connection not closed) and later os receives the data, how  does the java lib deal with the data?

Eg.Two tcp connections/sockets are in the connection pool. One thread reads timeout  and return(release the connection to the connection pool) and then another thead uses the same connection; then another thead maybe receives the response data of the first thread. I think it's not right. How does java lib(eg.httpclint) prevent another thread from receiving the response data of the previous thread's request when two threads use the same connection in turn?

Thx!

Comment: When there is a read timeout there is *no* received data. There is a read timeout *instead.* That answers the 'how does the Java lib deal with ...' part. The situation you describe where 'two connections/sockets are in the connection pool' where both sockets are the same is not realistic. Obviously the timed-out socket should have been closed instead of being returned to the connection pool.

Comment: @user207421 Thx. "Obviously the timed-out socket should have been closed instead of being returned to the connection pool"-is there a reference? I'v never heard such saying before.

Comment: @user207421 I read the relevant source code about Apache HttpClient, u r right. When HttpRequestExecutor encountered exceptions(Runtime/IO/Http Exception) it closed the connection(clear input buffer and flush output buffer). But it is a bit weird that even the connection isn't closed, now the peer cannot send data to the socket. Maybe I should go deeper.

Comment: You 'haven't encountered such a saying before' because it's obvious. No reference required. The socket that incurred the read timeout may or may not have incoming data related to the prior transaction, indeed may or may not even have a functioning peer, so it makes no sense whatsoever to return it to the pool. And 'even [if] the connection isn't closed, now the peer cannot send data to it' is simply untrue. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @user207421 No actual problem, lol. 'even if the connection isn't closed, the peer cannot send data to the socket' I mean the peer cannot send data after the connection read timeout happening(the connection not closed). I just debug a demo of  Apache HttpClient. The socket reads timeout and current thread is suspended at the breakpoint of closeConnection() call and then the peer sends data. Resume the suspended thread 10s later, however the peer always throws exception of connection closed.

Comment: There is no such error as 'connection closed. Do you mean 'connection reset by peer'? That means, err, that the peer's peer, i.e. your client, *has* closed the connection, which is exactly what it should do, rather than returning it to the pool.

Comment: @user207421 Thx a lot. Yes, connection reset by peer("remote host forced closed an occoured connection"). But the caller is suspended;  that is to say, the caller doesn't close socket yet. At this time the server should send data to the caller successfully. Afterwards the caller closes the connection. Why server throws IOException?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what kind of data you are receiving here. If it is strictly based on which thread will handle the received data, then you need to make sure the data is identified using some kind of a GUID and Thread ID combination so that the sender and receiver know that the message has been consumed or lost. Ideally, you should not have a situation where your logic is dependent on the underlying threads unless that logic is OS-layer specific.